# Toggle Button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, togglebutton

Is there any way I can use a regular ASP.NET button as a toggle button? There seems to be a simple way of doing it using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox), but I would prefer to use a regular button since I need very specific theming. Also, I need the button to refresh an UpdatePanel according to its toggled status.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using AJAX: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx

Or custom: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/ToggleControls.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As kuru kuru suggested, your best bet is probably the ToggleButton that comes with the AJAX Toolkit. I don't know if you use any control suites, but Telerik also has a nice Toggle button in their ASP.NET AJAX controls.